# Which one is the optimal risky portfolio in the efficiency frontier in the absense of a risk free asset?

Tags: portfolio-management

I know that the tangency point between the CAL line (drawn from risk-free asset's return) and the efficiency frontier is the optimal risky portfolio. But what if there is no risk free asset? Can I draw CAL line without risk free asset? How do I find the optimal risky portfolio on the efficient frontier?

Comment: I thought the original approach was to build your indifference curves and select the portfolio that lies on the intercept the most upper-left curve and the efficient frontier.

Answer (score 2):

"Fischer Black (1972) developed another version of CAPM, called Black CAPM or zero-beta CAPM, that does not assume the existence of a riskless asset" Source : [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_asset_pricing_model#Inventors)

In this model there is no straight line CAL, but investors can choose a point on the (curved) efficient frontier that provides a suitable risk/return combination, by holding a mix of the Market Portfolio and the Zero Beta Portfolio, a portfolio orthogonal to the Market Portfolio. The chosen point is where the investor's iso-utility curve is tangent to the efficient frontier.

Look up Black CAPM or Zero Beta CAPM for more details.